# Avoid nested components in AEM 6

Tags: aem

I have an AEM container component which just include the parsys where i can drag and drop any component other than same container component. Is there any way i can restrict this container component to be used inside "parsys of a container" but should be able to used in "parsys inside page".

This is done to avoid the nesting of container component inside the another container component.

Any pointers will be highly appreciated!!

Comment: Have you tried to remove container component in design mode for the "parsys of a container" from allowed components list?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by adding a design in `/etc/designs/<your-project-name>`.

The JCR structure would look something like this:

```
+-+ etc
  +-+ designs
    +-+ <your project> (cq:Page)
      +-+ jcr:content (nt:unstructured)
        +-+ <name of your page template> (nt:unstructured)
          +-+ parsys (nt:unstructured)
            +-+ <name of your container component>
              +-+ parsys (nt:unstructured)
                +-* components String[]
```

Most important is the property named `components` of type `String[]`. This is the list of components that is allowed to be placed in the `parsys` of your container component. The components in the list are identified by their `sling:resourceType`.

Example:

`components=[/apps/<your-projectname>/components/<component-name>,...]`

This mechanism gives you fine-grained control over which components are allowed on a page or in another component.

If you are not already using `/etc/designs` you probably will have to update your page templates and set `cq:designPath` to `/etc/designs/<your-project-name>`.

To see how this works you could have a look at the geometrixx design that you can find here `/etc/designs/geometrixx/jcr:content`.

Comment: Hi Jens - i think your solution would be tied up with the page template. What happens if i have more than 10 templates and everywhere i should be able to use this functionality. Then do i need to do the same thing in all 10 templates.

Comment: @user2581831 Usually you will end up doing this for all of your page templates. But I think this is ok. First off: You should not have _that_ many page templates and components. Second: You usually do this once and then only do incremental updates. So it is not that much work. And it is the "AEM" way of doing something like this, which is better than a home grown workaround solution.

Comment: String[] list allows components allowed to be used. Is there any way to use all components but not container. My components list is very huge, i don't wan to define each component there. Also, if someone adds a new component, then that component needs to be added in that list. if missed, then it cannot be used.

Comment: I am afraid you will have to add every component. And yes you have to add every new component as well. But as I said: You should not have so many components in the first place (about 15-20 is a normal). And normally you would do quality assurance so that you find out if a component was not added to the list.

Comment: Looks like there is no dev work involved here(allowed component list gets created automatically when someone like admin selects the components from design mode ) other than defining the design path at the content root level.please confirm? Also, it means every time author drag and drop the container component on the page, someone (may be admin) has to go to design mode and allow the components to be used there. If that is the case, then it will delay the work of author and always would have dependency on the admin to set allowed component list.

Comment: @user2581831 It is basically only dev work. But I get the feeling we are talking about different things or I am not able to explain well enough. What usually happens: Your company writes a specification together with your customer. In this specification you define which page templates and components your company should build. At the same time you specify which components are allowed to be used on which of the page templates. This is something only the customer can do because they know their business and requirements. And then you create this design in "code" and ship it. No admin needed.